Помогите подключить принтер
Требуется помощь по подключению принтера.
Вообщем, суть такая.
Имеется старенький Keenetic 2 к нему по USB цепляется принтер HP LaserJet 1010. Принтер виден по шаре в домашней сети. На новом ноутбуке под Windows 11  подключаюсь по шаре к роутеру видно, что есть принтер пытаюсь подключится, выдаёт ошибку 
Главное, что на стационарном компе под управлением Windows 10 этот принтер спокойно добавляется. Сами драйвера на принтер установлены.


Лучший вариант просто обновить драйверы через приложение HP.

При добавлении сетевого принтера вы можете получить ошибку, которая гласит: «Windows не может подключиться к принтеру. Операция завершилась с ошибкой 0x00000006».

0x00000006
Если вы попробуете снова, вы можете получить ошибку, которая гласит: «Windows не может подключиться к принтеру. Принтеры не найдены».
нет принтеров
Чтобы решить эту проблему, откройте редактор реестра (regedit) и перейдите к HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers. На всякий случай сделайте резервную копию ключа Client Side Rendering Print Providers. Затем удалите ключ Client Side Rendering Print Providers. Закройте редактор реестра. Перезапустите службу Print Spooler. Теперь попробуйте снова добавить принтер, и вы не должны получить ошибку.
2. Удалить и установить драйвер через консольную команду
printui.exe /s /t2
